# Forcing layout to display field in a particular font

Tags: fonts, filemaker

I am using Filemaker 12. When users input data, they seem to be able to paste text in various fonts/font-sizes/font-colors. I want the text to be displayed in the font of my choosing (in a layout) rather than in the font which it was pasted in as.

*(At the moment, the saved font displays rather than the prescribed layout-font.)*

How can I override the stored font, and display it in the text in the font of my choosing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to force it at the layout level, but you can have an auto-enter calculation that removes the formatting each time the the field gets new data; see the text formatting functions.

You can also replace the Paste menu command, but I would not recommend it, as this replacement stays in FileMaker dialogs, including the define fields dialog and makes them very inconvenient. (This may have changed in the recent version.)

Also, there's a way to do this on an ad-hoc basis: if you pasted formatted text, you can revert it to non-formatted by pressing the undo shortcut.

Comment: I ended up setting this (auto-enter calculation, checking on changes - I wish I had set this from the beginning), and then went back through all the changes which had been made adding and removing a space - fortunately these were logged and there was only about 50 or so!